# What should i import in java to perform connection pooling for db2 and tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, db2, database-connection, connection-pooling

I was using these imports in jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*,javax.naming.*,org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.*" ...
```

But when i try to use same imports , java gives error at line

```
Connection con=datasource.getConnection();
```

that "Connection cannot be resolved to a type".

So what imports should i use?

Comment: It ought to be in java.sql.connection... which version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing with a Wildcard, can you specify from the collection the "Connection" you want to use.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
```